# Rebranding a website to get a professional look

Tags: website-design, branding

I am a web developer student, and I usually think too much on user experience when it comes to designing websites (colors, interaction, etc.). This concerns me a lot when it comes to the creative process of creating new concepts.

I recently got a school assignment with a client. The client is a bus company. The problem is that I am struggling a lot with the colors of the company to get a professional look to the website. The old website needed a total rebranding so here is one of the big difficulties, especially for a web developer.

This is their bus:
[image: Bus]

This is an early prototype of the landing page (*The slider picture isn’t correct cropped. Also the footer content isn’t correctly aligned.*):
[image: Prototype]
Link to original website: [teamtour.no](http://teamtour.no/)

**Therefore**, my complex question is how can I accomplish a result that looks modern and professional?
And how can I get the look of the brand/bus to the website?

Any ideas and suggestions will be highly appreciated...

Comment: modern and professional?

Comment: How about a [hero image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_image) layout. With something akin to [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/127724047@N06/15016045960), but maybe quite much edited and not that exact picture. Possibly with bus in foreground. Mainly because their brand is sightseeing. So if you can arange a shooting in a scenic place... Maybe no rainbow.

Comment: @jooja I think your comment is a good enough answer it's a suggestion that answers the question.

Comment: The green is your main color, the blue is the highlight, ignore the rainbow and sun. Don't adapt bad design just because it's pre-existing. A "modern and professional layout" is up to you.

Comment: @joojaa I second Jenna, make that an answer! :)

Comment: Do your research and ask "Why?" a lot. Why are the buses green? Why do they have their current graphic profile? What needs and purposes does it fulfill? What was the idea behind the rainbow? Etc. etc. Then base your design on those reasons/answers instead of off the current design. And if those reasons suck, then make up better ones that the bus company might not have considered. For example: "the buses are largely green because they're eco-friendly". You shouldn't lie of course, just find things to highlight and use as selling points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Modern" is a relative term, whereas "Professional" is not.

Professional means:

- to respect basic graphic design rules - symmetry, grid rules, color theory, and so on. Some of these rules are basically a given if you work with a grid-based framework and have a good eye for esthetics. For more details check out this great [slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/nikoutabaee/principles-of-graphic-design-basics).
- to have clean, error free, and bug free code. You can use the  [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your code for syntax errors.

As for "modern", that is a relative term. If you should, however, want to "go with the flow", there are always trends you can follow. You can browse theme marketplaces, like [Themeforest](http://www.themeforest.net), read online magazines like [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) or just google for results and see what is more relevant to your case.

Comment: "Professional" is just as ambiguous as "modern" to me.

Comment: "Professional" to me means respecting standards and rules. While in coding it's pretty obvious what these standards are, in design, aside from composition and color rules, there are many variables, like personal taste, that make the term "professional" so ambiguous.

Comment: Its not obvious what professionalism means in coding either.

Comment: Who says *professional* means "respecting standards and rules"???? I know a ton of "professionals" who do neither. Does that not make them professionals?

Comment: @Scott "Professional" means "doesn't look like the neighbor's kid did it in MSPaint and pasted it into Word."

Comment: @LaurenIpsum really? You sure? http://www.toyota.co.jp/en/kids/toyota/index.html (yes that's a real Toyota web site) [oh lord.. just found this: http://www.lingscars.com/ ]

Comment: @Scott Yep, I'm sure. The Toyota one is obviously on purpose (although what that deranged purpose is I'm not sure) and the other one is not professional.

Comment: @Scott As, I said, that is what _professional_ means **to me**. And to many clients. It does not necessarily apply to everyone. With that in mind, may I say that even the two websites you suggested respect certain design "rules" while ignoring others (mostly the second one).  Obviously this is all relative to the goal of your website and the message you want express. Some situations deliberately require the breaking of certain "rules".

Answer (score 0):

kvambaam:

You can always go the easy route of taking their corporate colors, making pretty grid-based layout using flat design and calling it a day.

Or you can start from examining your client's needs:

- Get access to their Google analytics data to see what browsers / devices are used to access their site
- Confirm with client that these are relevant for next build
- Check with client if the site needs to go beyond simple rebranding, such as increased functionality, integration with sales and reservations, etc.
- Look into technology that supports relevant browsers and functionality - possibly open source framework like WordPress or Drupal
- Once technology is identified, look for template solutions for that technology.  For instance, if client is ok with WordPress and wants a responsive site, look for responsive WordPress templates that will work for you aesthetically
- Get or purchase template solution, deploy it as test site and brand it without changing template's layout or functionality

Depending on the complexity of the site, your project might be going beyond designing interactive pages and actually in the realm of "skinning" web-based software, in which case the website is driven by business logic and technology requirements.  I've seen many creatives put visuals first regardless of project's nature, resulting in stunning layouts that required a small fortune to execute as a custom build.